# Mobile jquery page transition issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm new to jquery mobile. Recently, I was working on mobile jquery + phonegap for ipad. I found various issues especially with page transition. I google out and found an issue here as well https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/455 but couldn't found any way out.
Using a4.0 mobile jquery:
1) I used $.mobile.changePage(url,"fade") method as I want to have transition effect when an external .html page is requested. But I noticed a strange issue that no javascript could run on that page( On the other.html, I have a div which fetch some data from database based on requested page using javascript and sqlite database). I googled out and found that this was because $.mobile.changePage calls through ajax.

2) I even tried out window.location.href=url, but no transition effect was shown.

Using b3 mobile jquery:
When used this version I found that blinky effect when transition was used as been discussed on https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/455 .

What I want is smooth transition like flip,fade etc. So please guide what i should do to get desired result.

Comment: I have used JQM 1.0RC1 version, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar problems just using standard data-role pages especially in going back. I think JQuery Mobile is aware of this as a CSS/CSS3 compatible fix. March 2012 is ETA.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to ditch the transition for this as they use AJAX.

For external links in jQuery mobile, you need to use 'rel="external"' on your link.